# Get Max of two summed rows on the same time stamp

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have certain meters each with their individual ID's. These meters record volumes on an hourly basis. Some meters will be linked together and their ID's will be 1 digit difference i.e. (1999990 and 1999991). I need to find the hour in which the sum of these two meter's volume is the greatest.

I've tried doing a Max function but I've come up short and get two results, instead of just one. I've tried to use a ranking over partition attempt, but received a similar result. The query I have below is the closest I think I've come to be able to sum them both and find the max but now I'm getting an invalid number error.

```
            SAMPLE DATA

   Meter     Hourly Volume  TimeStamp
   --------|---------------|-------------------
   1999990       25          02-21-2017 10:00am
   1999991       19          02-21-2017 10:00am
   1999990       20          02-21-2017 3:00pm
   1999991       16          02-21-2017 3:00pm
```

So here is some sample data to better clarify the intended results. The meters that are off by one digit need to have the volume added together on the same hour. So at 10:00am we would add up 25+19 = 44. Then we would add up 3:00pm 20+16 = 36. So out of those two we would want to select the 10:00am record because it is the largest one from the data.

```
SELECT B.METER_NAME, 
to_char(B.effectiveDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
MAX(B.summedVOLUME)

from

    (SELECT  
     A.METER_NAME,
     to_char(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as effectiveDate, 
     SUM(A.ADJUSTED_TOTAL_VOLUME) AS summedVolume

     FROM 

         (SELECT METER_NUMBER, METER_NAME, HOURLY.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 
          HOURLY.ADJUSTED_TOTAL_VOLUME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
          METER_NUMBER ORDER BY ADJUSTED_TOTAL_VOLUME DESC) rank
          FROM METER, HOURLY, METER_CHARACTERISTIC


          WHERE METER.METER_NUMBER_INDEX = HOURLY.METER_NUMBER_INDEX
          AND METER.METER_NUMBER_INDEX = 
          METER_CHARACTERISTIC.METER_NUMBER_INDEX
          AND HOURLY.METER_NUMBER_INDEX = 
          METER_CHARACTERISTIC.METER_NUMBER_INDEX

          METER_STATUS = 'A'
          AND METER.METER_NUMBER LIKE 
          ('%' || (SUBSTR(meter.meter_number, 0,6)) || '%' )

          AND ADJUSTED_TOTAL_VOLUME IS NOT NULL
          AND MEASUREMENT_MONTH = '201702'
        )A      

    WHERE A.rank = 1 
    group by A.METER_NAME, A.EFFECTIVE_DATE ) B  
group by B.METER_NAME, B.effectiveDate
;
```

I expect to get the max of both meters summed for a particular hour. However, I'm now getting an "ORA-01722 invalid number" once I added the outermost query.

EDIT: Left out a piece of code that could be causing issue. The substr function to identify the meter_number may be causing it.

Comment: This is not clear enough. If you have data for twenty meters in the same table, which meter (or pair of meters) does the query need to return the answer? Then: if you have meters with ID 103, 104, 105, which meters are linked - 103 and 104, or 104 and 105? Or all three? Or is this situation impossible (in which case you should say so, since it is not obvious from what you said). Then: What if the sum for the two meters is exactly the same for two different hours (say, 10 am and 3 pm)? What should the query return then?

Answer (score 0):

Looking just at why you're getting that error, and not at the overall task you're trying to perform, it's being thrown because your outer query is doing:

```
SELECT B.METER_NAME, 
to_char(B.effectiveDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
```

but the inline view `B` is doing:

```
SELECT  
     A.METER_NAME,
     to_char(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as effectiveDate,
```

which means that `B.effectiveDate` *is already a string*. If the underlying date value is, say, 2019-01-30 01:23:34, then the outer query is trying to do:

```
to_char('01/30/2019 01:23:34', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

and as you're passing a string in it defaults to [the numeric version of that function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_CHAR-number.html) (you know it's representing a date but Oracle doesn't, so it has to guess which version to use) and tries to implicitly convert the first argument to a number, as that's what the function expects; so really it's trying to do:

```
to_char(to_number('01/30/2019 01:23:34'), 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

and it's the implicit `to_number('01/30/2019 01:23:34')` which is throwing the ORA-01722 error.

You need to remove one of the conversions; either:

```
SELECT B.METER_NAME, 
B.effectiveDate,
MAX(B.summedVOLUME)

from

    (SELECT  
     A.METER_NAME,
     to_char(A.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') as effectiveDate,
```

or preferably (so the date value is converted to a string at the last possible moment):

```
SELECT B.METER_NAME, 
to_char(B.effectiveDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
MAX(B.summedVOLUME)

from

    (SELECT  
     A.METER_NAME,
     A.EFFECTIVE_DATE,
```